# How to restore favorite in Edge from OneDrive favorites folder?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, onedrive, bookmarks, microsoft-edge

I use to keep all my Bookmarks on Windows 10 on IE11 and backed them on the OneDrive Favorites folder.
But since IE11 had been discontinued I was maintaining the Favorites manually in the OneDrive Favorites folder as I was not sure which browser will be the default Browser for Personal use.
Now I have decided on the browser, none of the Chromium based browsers allow restoring the Bookmarks from a folder.

Is there a way to create an `.html` file from OneDrive in the format in which the Chromium based browsers can import Favorites?

Edit: I tried restoring by using Import from InternetExplorer option in both the [chrome://settings/importData](https://chrome://settings/importData) and [edge://settings/profiles/importBrowsingData](https://edge://settings/profiles/importBrowsingData) but that didn't restore anything although it gave success message.

Comment: HI, your question doesn't quite make sense to me. Do you want to recover from IE11 (question body) or Edge (title)? To where, Google Chrome, since that's in your tags? Or just any modern Chromium browser? If so, please delete that tag.

Comment: @Destroy666, i would like to restore the Bookmarks which i have backed up in Favorites folder of one drive. Regarding where part i want to import them in Edge or Google chrome, both are chromium based. The issue is i tried the import from IE option but that doesn't restore anything.

Comment: What you have now is a folder tree full of `.url` internet links, right? With some programming, it will be trivial to create a bookmarks HTML file out of it.

Comment: @Vipresh you should edit the question to be more accurate and remove the Chrome tag then as I mentioned.

Comment: @DanielB, yes I have a folder full of .url files, but as suggested by someone,I tried enabling IE11, restored the bookmarks, and then again tried the import option in Edge & it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing Internet Explorer favorites to Chrome is done this way:

- In Chrome, type "chrome://settings/importData" into the address bar
- Select "Internet Explorer" from the drop-down menu and verify that `Favorites/Bookmarks` is checked (if shown, other items are optional)
- Click Import.
  When the import is complete, you will see a confirmation screen
  that says "Your bookmarks and settings are ready".
- Click Done.

For more details with screenshots, see for example
[How to Import Bookmarks to Chrome](https://sonomacounty.ca.gov/administrative-support-and-fiscal-services/information-systems/how-to-instructions/how-to-import-bookmarks-to-chrome).

---

If there is a problem with starting IE11, know that its underlying
software is still installed on Windows 10.

Try executing
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"`.
You could also use a one-line VBS file with `CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application").Visible=true`.

If it doesn't work, then you may have disabled it in
"Turn Windows features on or off", but this is just the
user interface, while the underlying software is still there
and will stay there forever, because it's used by Windows API
and still available in Edge.

The easiest for you in this case will be to re-enable IE11,
get the favorites into Chrome, then disable it again if you
so wish.

If you don't see your exported favorites in IE11, you may
use `regedit` to position to the registry key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\user Shell Folders`
and set the item `Favorites` to point to your favorites file.
This registry change might be enough by itself to let Chrome
detect the favorites to be imported.

Comment: This answer indirectly also applies to any Chromium based browser

Comment: Please describe how it didn’t work. Did it pretend to finish successfully but did not import anything? Or did an error message pop up?

Comment: IE11 is still installed on Windows 10. Try executing `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"`. If it doesn't work, then you have disabled it in "Turn Windows features on or off", but this is just the user interface, and the underlying software is still there and will stay there forever because used by Windows API and available in Edge. The easiest for you in this case will be to re-enable IE11, get the favorites into Chrome, then disable it again if you wish.

Comment: @harrymc thanks this helped, If u post this as answer I will accept it.Few problems i faced while doing this was that on running the above command Edge Chromium used to load instead of IE11. On googling I came across a solution that suggested creating a vbs file with one line CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application").Visible=true, then i was able to load IE11. Again IE11 didnt reflect any of my favorites,on further googling i found that the folder location is pointed at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\user Shell Folders, i pasted my favorites & it worked

Comment: I've included this info in my answer.

Comment: @Vipresh - IE11 hasn't been removed from Windows 10.  That will happen in June 203. You can't launch it since it's indirectly been disabled.  However, that does not prevent you from importing your favorites into a Chromium-based browser.